# Scrapy: how to check websites if they contain a certain string

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to iterate through many websites and see if they contain a certain string. E.g. "biscuit". Using scrapy

Comment: download HTML and check it. HTML is as string so you can check like `if "biscuit" in HTML`

Comment: start with this website: [Scrapy.org](https://scrapy.org/) and [ToScrape.com](http://toscrape.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Learn and use **Scrapy**.

```py
def parse(self, response):
    if 'biscuit' in response.text:
        print('Found!')
    else:
        print('Not found!')
```

Scrapy Docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/

Comment: I see. Wouldn't this require me to have downloaded the HTML already? I am trying to do a large number of websites at once. Like a few each second. I want this to be automated. Checking them without me downloading it that is.